# very large memory used by processes

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

so i'm currently writing this program that gathers information about processes running on my pc, this infos include time spent using the application, memory allocated and  lots more.
Now the fascinating part of this program is when i run my scripts to figure the amount of memory being utilized by an application and it's processes, i get this very large figure (e.g for chrome i get 601960204kb which is equivalent to about 601gb which is seems really unrealistic), i'd really like to know why processes memory gets that large when they are running.
PS: i'm a complete newbie to linux and system programming too :)

def get_total_process_memory(process_list:list):
cmd = None
total_memory_for_PID = []

```
for i in ids:
    cmd = os.popen("pmap {0}".format(int(i))).read()
    total_memory_for_PID.append(cmd.splitlines( )[-1].strip())


memory = [i[12:].strip() for i in total_memory_for_PID]
sum_of_memory_used = 0
for i in memory:
    sum_of_memory_used += int(i[0:-1])
return sum_of_memory_used
```

Comment: `pmap` shows all mapped virtual memory, not just RAM. Regions can be shared with other processes, backed by disk, reserved but unallocated, and other states that don't contribute to RAM usage. Different tools calculate memory usage differently because there is no single, universally agreed upon definition.

Comment: Also, it's Chrome:)

Comment: hi guys thanks for the responses :) was just curious why processes consumed that much, anyways i would do further digging on me own to come up with more solid explanations.